# Why does Log4j accept un-numbered bracket syntax for log message placeholders?

Tags: java

By default log4j2 allows you to format a message using Java's `MessageFormat` syntax. In fact, spelunking among the classes provided by the framework, I found a `MessageFormatMessage` implementation

log4j2 accepts `log.info("User {} entered secure area at {}",username,url);`

However it is known that if you want to use a placeholder-style syntax for writing to the console you **must** do `System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("User {0} entered secure area at {1}",username, url));`. It is less cool because you must always remember to write all arguments 0-based

I have spelunked more into the code and [found this](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/log4j-2.7/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MessageFormatMessage.java#L113)

```
protected String formatMessage(final String msgPattern, final Object... args) {
    try {
        final MessageFormat temp = new MessageFormat(msgPattern, locale);
        return temp.format(args);
    } catch (final IllegalFormatException ife) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to format msg: " + msgPattern, ife);
        return msgPattern;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is: since log4j call's Java Text's MessageFormat with the pattern it was given by the logger, and since it is my understanding log4j defaults to `MessageFormatMessage`, why can I call log4j with a pattern that has no argument numbers and I can't use `MessageFormat.format` with same omission?

It would be great to do the same log4j trick to format regular Java messages all around my code

Comment: I even saw people using string concatenation instead, as `{}` placeholders was something they did not guess/try. Of course if you have a **fixed** order numbers are not a good idea. And if still complex arguments, you are stuck with `{date}` and such. Numbers are good for internationalization only.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the concatenation (but then when you write localized resources you are all f£$%ed up), but I don't get the point on complex arguments. I still need to number them. Rewording just in case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default message factory in Log4j2 is [`ParameterizedMessageFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessageFactory.html).

This is the one that accepts format strings using the parameter marker `{}`.

The method you came up with is part of the `MessageFormatMessage` class which in turn is used by a different message factory, called [`MessageFormatMessageFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MessageFormatMessageFactory.html). When you decide to use this factory instead, Log4j2 will only accept format strings conforming to `java.text.MessageFormat`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a parenthesis log message in order to solve your warning:

```
static final LOG_MESSAGE =
        "cnmService.sendCnmMessage didnt work. serviceResult.getStatus.getCode(): {}";
```

Instead of:

```
static final LOG_MESSAGE =
        "cnmService.sendCnmMessage didnt work. serviceResult.getStatus.getCode(): ";
```